# mark_safe not working/still escaping in simple_tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm using Django 1.3 and I have a simple_tag that I need to return some un-escaped HTML and no matter what I do it's still escaping my & to &amp; and my | to %7C.

```
from django import template
from django.template import loader, Context
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag()
def show_stuff(arg1=None, arg2=None, arg3='someconstant'):

    # Do some stuff

    if someconstant == 'somevalue':
        template_name = 'template1.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'template2.html'

    template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    html = template.render(Context( {'myvar': myvar,} ))
    html = mark_safe(html)
    print type(html)
    return html
```

The print statement reveals

```
<class 'django.utils.safestring.SafeUnicode'>
```

which from my understanding isn't supposed to be escaped. I'm calling the tag in my template like so:

```
{% show_stuff 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' %}
```

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Update: Tried the following from comments below. Didn't return an error, but still escapes the HTML:

```
    ...
    template = loader.get_template(template_name)
    html = template.render(Context( {'myvar': myvar,} ))
    html = mark_safe(html)
    print type(html)
    return html
show_stuff().is_safe=True
```

Also tried wrapping the contents of template1.html and template2.html in

```
{% autoescape off %}
template html contents with & and |
{% endautoescape %}
```

and wrapping the templatetag call itself with autoescape tags. No success.

Comment: And @register.simple_tag( is_safe = True ) does not work too?

Comment: simple_tag() got an unexpected keyword argument 'is_safe' :/

Comment: OK, and what if you write your tag as: {% show_stuff|safe 'arg1' 'arg2' 'arg3' %} (remove is_safe = True)?

Comment: Tried that as well... maybe the syntax is incorrect. Returns Invalid block tag: 'show_stuff|safe', expected 'endblock' or 'endblock'

Comment: OK, remove this. Try to add the string to your html before return: html += "<b>Escaped?</b>". Is 'escaped' bold?

Comment: 'show_stuff().is_safe=True' is a error. It should be 'show_stuff.is_safe=True'

Comment: Corrected show_stuff.is_safe syntax, escaping still happens, BUT using your html += "<b>Escaped?</b>" suggestion, escaped is indeed properly bolded. So I tried html += "<b>Escaped?</b> | &" - The pipe works perfectly, which is actually the crux of my problem. Does this explain anything?

Comment: So, you have inserted the string just before return and | & is not escaped?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14483/discussion-between-sergzach-and-scoopseven)

Comment: It's too many discussion strings, let's go to the chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14483/discussion-between-sergzach-and-scoopseven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In discussion with the author of the question we found that the characters were not actually escaped. Scoopseven (the author) viewed the source html with the option "Show Selection Source" of a context menu in Firefox. In this case escaped characters are shown.

Comment: When using Firefox's "Show Selection Source" it displayed escaped HTML. Viewing the full source in Chrome or Firefox accurately displayed the non-escaped HTML. Thanks, sergzach.

Answer (score 6):

Old thread but I ran into the same issue recently. I got it working python 3.6. Assign the value from simple tag to a variable txt and output the txt using template tags "{{" and add safe filter to txt.

```
{% get_contentvalue user "htmlabout" as txt %}
{{txt|safe}}
```